# What is the quantity in physics that is advanced from speed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, education, velocity, speed, history

What is the quantity in physics that is advance from speed?

i know one is velocity, one is speed, one is acceleration.

Comment: It seems logical that speed is related to speed...

Comment: I am at a loss to determine what the question here is. In particular I don't understand *"is advanced from"* as it is used here. Can someone clarify the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give an overview of the different measurements encountered in kinematics (as there doesn't seem to be a real, precise question asked here).

The most familiar quantity we encounter in kinematics is speed. Speed is abstractly *how fast* something is going. It does not take into account direction, and is therefore known as a scalar quantity. It is what we measure on the speedometer of a car. Speed is often denoted by $v$ in physics.

Velocity takes into account both speed and direction. It is a vector quantity, and is often denoted by $\vec{v}$ or $\mathbf v$ in physics. Velocity is the rate of change of distance with respect to time, which in calculus notation is written:

$$\vec{v}=\mathbf{v}=\frac{d\vec{s}}{dt}$$

It is also useful to note that if we know the velocity, it is easy to find the speed, as we have the simple relationship:

$$v=\|\vec{v}\|=\|\mathbf{v}\|$$

Where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the [euclidean norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Euclidean_norm).

Acceleration formally is defined as the rate of change with velocity with respect to time, that is, it's a measurement of how fast the velocity is changing, so it is a vector quantity. That is, in calculus notation:

$$\vec{a}=\mathbf{a}=\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}=\frac{d^{2}\vec{s}}{dt^{2}}$$

However, it is also sometimes used to refer to the norm of that quantity. So you may also see:

$$a=\left\|\frac{d\vec{v}}{dt}\right\|=\|\vec{a}\|=\|\mathbf{a}\|$$

Bear in mind, there are also various higher derivatives (rates of change) which are occasionally used in kinematics, such as the derivative of acceleration with respect to time, called [*jerk*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerk_%28physics%29) and the derivative of that with respect to time, called [*jounce*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jounce).

I hope this helps clear things up a bit, if you still have questions, feel free to ask them in the comments.

Comment: As far as I know, the norm of $\mathbf{a}$ isn't the same as the derivative of the norm of $\mathbf{v}$. The latter is what is usually called tangential acceleration.

Comment: @JavierBadia: as written, they have a = the norm of the derivative, not the other way around.